# PostgreSQL: Create a series of numbers unique for a reference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made an example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0f948/9

1-to many is what I'm building, although many-to-many would be more real life for this example.

What I need to accomplish:
I should be able to generate author order depicting sequence of integers for the authororder-column in author-table, starting from number 1 so that every number is unique amongst the book-reference. So for every author set under a certain book-reference the numbers from 1 to 2, to 3 etc. 
Also the numbers for authororder should be generated to reflect the order of the author.fullname (as: 'select * from author order by fullname').

I tried using sequence, but is does not reset the sequence number for each book as I would like it to, instead the number continues to increase (as it should I guess). I also tried doing this with the help of row_number(), but could not manage to prepare a script which would achieve what I want it to.

The end result after generating the authororder would be something like this:

```
author_id       fullname          mobileno            fk_book_id           authororder
100           John Green            30303                 1                     (1)
101           Maureen Johnson       4343                  1                     (3)
102           Lauren Myracle        76665                 1                     (2)
103           Greg Mortenson        6434                  2                     (2)
104           David Oliver Relin    72322                 2                     (1)
105           Marco Polo            54321                 3                     (3)
106           Angus MacGyver        27234                 3                     (1)
107           Timo TA               83451                 3                     (4)
108           Anonymous             55554                 3                     (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
row_number() over (partition by fk_book_id order by fullname) as authororder
```

You can incorporate this into an update as:

```
update author a
    set authororder = new_authororder
    from (select a.*, 
                 row_number() over (partition by fk_book_id order by fullname) as new_authororder
          from author a
         ) aa
    where a.authorid = aa.authorid;
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! And how does one update the actual authororder values with the results from your snippet?